# Selecting the first match of a join

Tags: sql-server-2008

So I have a SQL Statement which returns something like this:

```
PLAYER_ID | PLAYER_NAME | POSITION | 
1           player1       hitter
1           player1       short stop
1           player1       pitcher
2           player2       pitcher
2           player2       catcher
```

This is done by an inner join between players and current_player_stats.

```
SELECT P.PLAYER_ID, P.PLAYER_NAME, S.POSITION
FROM PLAYERS AS P
INNER JOIN CURRENT_PLAYER_STATS AS S
ON P.PLAYER_ID = S.PLAYER_ID
WHERE P.PLAYER_ID = <some player id>
```

What SQL can I use to filter this result set to give me:

```
PLAYER_ID | PLAYER_NAME | POSITION | 
1           player1       hitter
2           player2       pitcher
```

i.e. the top row of each player.

Comment: if you show the SQL you are using, you may get some responses.

Comment: what does "top row" mean? (e.g. The most recent, the biggest/smallest Id)

Comment: How do you determine which row is the top row for each player?

Comment: How would you decide to pick which record from the join ?? do you just want one record for each player or whats the logic of picking these two records that you have shown in your desired output ???

Comment: @w0lf It would be the most recent stat.  That field is based only on a date (not a datetime) and so it's possible and likely for two stats to have the same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the limited info provided lets try

```
;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT    Player_ID, 
              Player_Name, 
              Position, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Player_ID ORDER BY [Columns Here]) as RowID
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM Vals 
WHERE RowID = 1
```

Comment: So essentially what you're doing it assigning each row a row number and then selecting only the rows with a number of 1?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Do note the `partition by` and `order by` as this will determine when the row number gets reset, and in which order